# Pass JSON parameter in rest call using annotations

Tags: java, javascript, json, rest, backbone.js

This is my Backbone Model

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/baseModel'
], function (_, Backbone, BaseModel) {

    var category  = BaseModel.extend({
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.catId = options.catId;
        },
        url: function () {
            var test_json = {
                  k: {
                    k_catId: this.catId,
                    k_dateText: 'last30Days',
                    k_countryCode: $.cookie('countryCode'),
                  }
                }
            var json = JSON.stringify(test_json);
            return applicationUrl + "/service/user/brands/content-category/" + this.catId + "?dateText=last30Days&token=" + $.cookie('token') + "&countryCode=" + $.cookie('countryCode') + "&json=" + json
        }
    });
    return category;
});
```

I need this json to be passed to my java backend and want to get it through "@QueryParam" property. But it is showing that variable "json" can not be resolver. My java code is as follows:

```
@POST
    @Path("/content-category/{catId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public final Object getContentCategoryData(@Auth AuthToken userAuth, @PathParam("catId") long catId, @QueryParam("dateText") String dateText,
                                               @QueryParam("countryCode") String countryCode, @QueryParam("json") String json) {
        long userId = userAuth.getUserId();
        HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
          //some code
          }
      catch(Exception e){
        }
      }
```

Looking for any type of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stringified json can't be sent directly in the url as a query param without encoding.

```
var json = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the params as part of the URL, try amending the url to point to the endpoint and sending the params in a POST. I would use

```
model.set({
  yourData
});
```

then `model.save();`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have parameter for "token" in back-end?

```
@QueryParam("token") String token
```

Try adding it.

Comment: Thanks :-) But it is handled in AuthToken.